# How to translate Wordpress site and then keep it updated?

Tags: wordpress, web, translate, language-translation

I manage a wordpress website which I need to have translated and then maintained in all 3 languages going forward. 
So I want to have the translation integrated so that if there is an update to the content in English, I can easily submit the updated content for translation and then just import the changed, updated results back in.

We don't want to continuously copy and paste. obviously Google translate and Microsoft have API's but we require professional translation not machine translation.

Any ideas?

Comment: List of wordpress  translation Plugin : 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/
https://wpml.org/

Comment: Try WPML translation plugin too: https://wpml.org/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @ash-patel. Thats pretty much what I ended up with. I found a site called [www.translatewebsites.com](http://www.translatewebsites.com). They offer a professional, human translation service using the wpml.org plugin. I have submitted my site for translation into Traditional Chinese and if all goes well should be able to import the translated content without any manual work - fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a plugin called [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). I use it in a couple of websites and is very powerful (and free).